# Vue.js + eslint. Error Parsing error: Unexpected token @

Tags: node.js, vue.js, pycharm, eslint

I'm doing project Django Rest Framework + Vue.js
I've got a problem with eslint

**error  Parsing error: Unexpected token**

```
   5 |     <b-container>
   6 |       <b-row class="question-row">
>  7 |         <b-form @submit="onSubmit" @reset="onReset">
     |                 ^
   8 |           <b-form-group id="input-group"
   9 |                         :label="getQuestion(1)"
  10 |                         label-for="input-1">
```

here's my .eslintrc.json file

```
{
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:vue/essential",
    "plugin:vue/base"
  ],
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 7,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
      "modules": true
    }
  },
  "plugins": [
    "vue"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "max-len": ["error", {"code": 121}],
    "semi": ["error","always"],
    "no-console": 0
  }
}
```

and do I need babel.config.json? It was added to my project after initializing Vue project. Here's my code

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset',
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change @submit into v-on:submit